# Problema con la query laravel

Tags: php, laravel, sql, laravel-7

Tengo un formulario por el cual envío los datos: en el controller los recibo y relleno así:

```
    public function storePublicacion (Request $request) {
      //dd($request->all());
      $publicacion = new Publicaciones();
      $ultimoRegistro = Publicaciones::all()->last();
      $rutaImagen = '';
      if($ultimoRegistro != null) {
        $rutaImagen = 'publicaciones/'.($ultimoRegistro->id+1);
      } else {
        $rutaImagen = 'publicaciones/1';
      }
      //$publicacion->fill($request->all());
      $publicacion->fecha = $request->fecha;
      $publicacion->titulo = $request->titulo;
      $publicacion->titulo_en = $request->titulo_en;
      $publicacion->texto = $request->texto;
      $publicacion->texto_en = $request->texto_en;
      $publicacion->orden = $request->orden;
      $publicacion->visible = $request->visible;
      if($request->hasfile('imagen')) {
        $archivo = $request->file('imagen');
        //////////////////
        $nombreFoto = strtr($request->titulo, " ", "-");
        $nombreMinusculas = strtolower($nombreFoto);
        $extension = $archivo->getClientOriginalExtension();
        //////////////////
        $publicacion->imagen = $rutaImagen.'/'.$nombreMinusculas.'.'.$extension;
        dd($publicacion->imagen);
        $publicacion->save();

        $archivo->move(public_path().'/images/'.$rutaImagen, $nombreMinusculas.'.'.$extension);
      } else {
        dd("no entra");
        $publicacion->imagen = '';
        $publicacion->save();
      }
      return redirect('/publicacionesPrivado');
    }
```

El problema es que al hacer un dd($publicacion->imagen); me sale: **b"publicaciones/5/ una-nueva-publicaciã“n.jpeg"** me pone una b antes del valor y no entiendo de dónde sale.

Comment: Y si en vez de usar dd() usas var_dump() o print_r() ?? aparece lo mismo ??

Comment: Primer consejo, por favor utiliza PSR-12 y PHPCBF para indentar tu código. El request recibe lo que tu le envíes por qué no revisas bien que estás enviando en el formulario y además sería útil para tu pregunta colocar el formulario que envía la data al controlador y no estaría demás colocar también la ruta.

Comment: @Excorpion si seguía saliendo lo mismo. pero ya lo he solucionado.

Comment: @LuisAlfredoSerranoDíaz lo que hay que utilizar es es sistema UTF-8 para que coja los caracteres especiales, pero lo que yo quería era guardar sin caracteres especiales, ej: en el input del formulario enviaba publicación, lo quería guardar con publicacion. lo que hice fue reemplazar los caracteres y poner utf8_encode($variable) .